# Strophe XMPP using Angular 2

Tags: angular, strophe

I want to create service for Strophe.JS XMPP library in angular2 project. That service is responsible for Open and Close connection and include handler to receive message. I am able to do in .Net MVC project but i did not found a way to implement in Angular2 framework.

Thanks,
Sanjeev

Comment: did you find any solution ? as I am also looking for this but in angular 5

Answer (score 0):

First to install @types/strophe

```
npm install --save @types/strophe
```

Second to download Strophe library from [Strophe Site](http://strophe.im/strophejs/)

Then, You should put the framework inside **/src/assets/**

Then, You should add the script tag to the index.html before polyfills.js and main.js

Thus

```
<script src="assets/strophejs-1.2.14/strophe.js"></script>
```

Last,

you should put this declare statement before to use the strophe.

```
declare var Strophe: any;
```

It works for me!

I hope to help you.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Gobea. Any reason to reference strophe library before before polyfills.js and main.js? Right now i have define in Angular-Cli.json file. Is it ok?